# Activity cant find Bundle in Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, intentservice

I am using an `IntentService` (for the first time), and I intend to return the result of this service by using a Bundle. However, when I do this, the main activity does not find the `Bundle`, returning `null`. What could cause this? The string keys match!

The code bellow outputs:

```
I/System.out: It's null
```

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Some stuff here...

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(StorageHandler.TRANSACTION_DONE);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, StorageHandler.class);
        startService(i);
    }



    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extra = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");

            if(extra == null){
                System.out.println("It's null");
            }
            else {
                ArrayList<String> objects = (ArrayList<String>) extra.getSerializable("objects");
                System.out.println(objects.get(0));
            } 
        }
    };

}
```

**IntentService:**

```
public class StorageHandler extends IntentService{

    public static final String TRANSACTION_DONE = "xx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.TRANSACTION_DONE";

    public StorageHandler() {
        super("StorageHandler");
    }

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        notifyFinished();
    }

    private void notifyFinished(){
        ArrayList<String> objects = new ArrayList<String>();
        objects.add("Resulting Array here");

        Bundle extra = new Bundle();
        extra.putSerializable("objects", objects);

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(xx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.StorageHandler.TRANSACTION_DONE);
        i.putExtra("bundle", extra);

        StorageHandler.this.sendBroadcast(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to retrieve the data from the wrong `Intent`.

Change:

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

To:

```
Bundle extra = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

The `Intent` that contains your data is supplied as one of the parameters of the `BroadcastReceiver`'s [`onReceive()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) method.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `getIntent()` to retrieve the *broadcasted* intent. This is wrong. The intent you have to use is the former paramter of `onReceive`. Change

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

with

```
Bundle extra = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this in your Activity:

In `onResume` callback you should register `registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);`

And in `onPause` callback you should unregister this receiver. In your receiver use this:

`Bundle extra = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");`

In your service use this code:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(TRANSACTION_DONE).putExtra("bundle", extra);
            this.sendBroadcast(i);
```

More information , see [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33448943/3073945)

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget this in your onCreate MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     //All your code here
 }
```

I say this because I dont see that code line in your method!

Comment: That is included on the "Some stuff here..." area of the method. But thanks for the heads up.