# Android: Standard way to make a thread run every second

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to run  a `Thread` class every second. I cant use `Runnable`. I tried in the following way, but its throwing `StackOverflowException`. Can anyone please let me know a standard method to make a thread class run every second.

```
public class A extends Thread {

    public void run() {
       //do my stuff
      sleep(1*1000,0);
      run();
    }
}
```

Comment: this link will help [how-do-you-use-a-timertask-to-run-a-thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029831/how-do-you-use-a-timertask-to-run-a-thread

Answer (score 18):

Use [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)'s [`schedule()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) or [`scheduleAtFixedRate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) ([difference between these two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684604/android-timer-schedule-vs-scheduleatfixedrate)) with [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) in the first argument, in which you are overriding the `run()` method.

Example:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // TODO do your thing
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Your example causes stack overflow, because it's infinite recursion, you are always calling `run()` from `run()`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to consider an alternative like [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

/*This schedules a runnable task every second*/
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    DoWhateverYouWant();
  }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Cant we make a thread run every second?? I could have considered Runnable or ScheduledExecutorService, but i'm stuck in a scenario where I must use a thread. Please help.

Comment: @madhu : **"i'm stuck in a scenario where I must use a thread."** - Why? Explain the reason why you can't use other ways to do what you need to do. Also, explain what it is you need to do.

Comment: What if the task is taking long time and all the 5 threads are consumed? This won't work perfectly. See my answer :)

Comment: @sqonk: I'm calling this Thread from mainActivity. This Thread is an abstract class which is extended by 3 more classes. I've called an abstract method in Void Run() which are defined in these 3 classes. Intention is that, once this thread gets started, rest of the classes gets executed simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

```
final ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        es.submit(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // do your work here
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Can we use this inside a Class which extends Thread?? Or should I've to create a service class??

Comment: I tried to implement this method inside a Thread class. I was not working. I tried to debug and the flow was not getting entered into void run after scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable().