# What is the difference between schedule and scheduleAtFixedRate?

Tags: java

What is the difference between these 2 methods of `Timer` class :

```
schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

and

```
scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) doesn't make the difference between them clear.

Comment: Fixed delay vs fixed rate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Exactly. What is the difference ? Rate is _1 step per minute_ and delay is _1 minute for a step_

Comment: In fixed delay, the execution is relative to the last execution. In fixed rate, it's fixed rate.

Comment: The Answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684604/android-timer-schedule-vs-scheduleatfixedrate

Have fun

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't get it. Both are relative to last execution

Comment: In fixed rate, it doesn't matter how long the previous execution took, the next execution will happen when it was scheduled. With fixed-delay, the next execution will happen X time after the previous finished, even if it was late.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The documentation does explain the difference:

schedule:

> In fixed-delay execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the actual execution time of the previous execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), subsequent executions will be delayed as well.

So, suppose the delay is 5 seconds, and each task takes 2 seconds, you would get

```
TTWWWTTWWWTTWWWTT
```

where `T` means 1 second for the task execution, and `W` means 1 second waiting.

But now suppose that a long GC (represented by a `G`) happens and delays the second task, the third one will start 5 seconds after the start of the second one, as if the long GC didn't happen:

```
TTWWWGGTTWWWTTWWWTT
```

The third task starts 5 seconds after the second one.

scheduleAtFixedRate:

> In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up.".

So, with the same delay as above, and the same GC, you would get

```
TTWWWGGTTWTTWWWTT
```

The third task task starts 3 seconds instead of 5 after the second one, to catch up.

Comment: Thanks, I already understood from other answers the concept, but the `TWG` example was very clear. Question: if I have longer tasks, for example 7 secs and 4s, with `scheduleAtFixedRate` will I have something like `T1T1T1T1T1.T1T1T2T2T2.T2T3T3WW` ?

Comment: In `scheduleAtFixedRate()`, if a task takes long time to complete. Suppose each task takes roughly 2secs to complete and there is a delay of 3secs between each task. So in normal execution it will be `TTWTTWTTW...`

But for some reason, task-2 takes 5 secs to complete, when will task-3 start? Will it start at 6th sec as before or at 8th sec waiting for task-2 to complete

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Nizet's answer, I have written a sample code for some people who want to practice and learn.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        TimerTest.DelayTask task = new DelayTask();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        /**
         * Use schedule or scheduletAtFixedrate and check the printed result
         */
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);
        //timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 5000);
    }

    public static boolean stop = false;

    public static void delayOneSec(String status){
        try{
            System.out.print(status);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class DelayTask extends TimerTask{
        int count = 2;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            stop = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                TimerTest.delayOneSec("T");
            }
            if(count == 2){
                count = 6;
            }else{
                count = 2;
            }
            stop = false;
            new PrintW().start();
        }
    }

    static class PrintW extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(!stop){
                TimerTest.delayOneSec("W");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The task itself will repeat to take 2 seconds or 6 seconds. Let's see the result of each scenario.

When using `timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);`, the output is `TTWWWTTTTTTTTWWWTTTTTTTTWWWTTTTTTTT`. As you can see, the timer follow the rules like below, wait till `period` time outs if task finishes in time, launch next task immediately if current task lasts more than `period`.

When using `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 5000);`, the output is `TTWWWTTTTTTTTWWTTTTTTTTWWTTTTTTTTWWTTTTTTTTWWTTTTTTTTWWTTTTTTTT`. Things are a little different now. The javadoc

> two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up."

takes effect here. As you can see, ignoring the first `TTWWW`, every two tasks will print `TTTTTTTTWW` and it lasts 10 seconds(two periods).

Let's dig into the source code of `Timer`.

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period) {
    if (period <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-positive period.");
    sched(task, firstTime.getTime(), -period);
}


public void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) {
    if (delay < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative delay.");
    if (period <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-positive period.");
    sched(task, System.currentTimeMillis()+delay, period);
}
```

As you can see, the `period` is transferred to negative value in `schedule` method. Let's see what's the difference when scheduling it.

The below code is in the `mainloop` of `TimerThread`,

```
currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
executionTime = task.nextExecutionTime;
if (taskFired = (executionTime<=currentTime)) {
    if (task.period == 0) { // Non-repeating, remove
        queue.removeMin();
        task.state = TimerTask.EXECUTED;
    } else { // Repeating task, reschedule
        queue.rescheduleMin(
        task.period<0 ? currentTime   - task.period
                      : executionTime + task.period);
           }
    }
}
```

It's where magic happens, for `schedule` method, the next task execution time is based on the `currentTime` which is calculated right before the this task runs. That means, every task's execution time only be related with previous task starts time.