# Job not executing at fixed rate

Tags: spring-mvc, jobs, execution

I have the following spring mvc configuration:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="defaultScheduler">
   <task:scheduled ref="myTaskWorker" method="someMethod"
     fixed-rate="500" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

When I execute the above it is not executed in every 500ms but only executed after the finishing of the previous one.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: It is not suppose to spun a new thread when there is already a thread with same job in process?

Comment: @java_dude Then what is the exact difference between fixed-delay and fixed-rate?And can you please help me to fix my issue (initiating a new request irrespective of previous thread is being finished after a certain period of time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is about time rather than number of tasks. `Fixed rate` will keep track of time and spun new thread to match the fixed-time of 5 seconds. So in short, you would not have multiple threads as you are expecting.

In 15 seconds, there should be three executions. But if first task takes 10 seconds and second task takes 6 seconds then on 16th second, third task is going to start. And next task, would start on 20th second (fixed-rate), only if the third task is complete by then. Hope this makes sense.

Check out detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486997/what-is-the-difference-between-schedule-and-scheduleatfixedrate)