# Run task periodically in Java using java.util.TimerTask

Tags: java

While scheduling tasks using java.util.TimerTask how i can make sure that run method will execute only after current execution is completed, otherwise tasks queue size will keep growing and eventually task will be executing always. i am beginner and looking help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ExecutorService#scheduleWithFixedDelay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). This will start the 'delay' when the current task finishes (as opposed to `scheduleAtFixedRate()`)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) with the [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html). One of these timer's two methods can be used:

- `schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`
- `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`

Where:
`task` - task to be scheduled.
`delay` - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
`period` - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.

Also, refer this article: [What is the difference between schedule and scheduleAtFixedRate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486997/what-is-the-difference-between-schedule-and-scheduleatfixedrate)