# How start a method in when the current seconds equal 00

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

I'm working on a method in a service class in Android Studio..
I used Timer to re-execute the method every one minute.. but the seconds is matter in my case..
when the `onStartCommand` lunched at **for example** 13:40:22, the `forRoom1()` method we will execute and wait one minute so it will be re-executed at 13:41:22..

I want the `forRoom1()` method to start its first execution at 13:40:00 so after waiting one minute it will re-executed at 13:41:00..

here is my onStartCommand code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {

forRoom1();

}
}, 0, 60 * 1000);



return START_STICKY;
}
```

whatever is the current time, the most important thing is to start is first execution at second 00
can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step we must know the second of Current time, then the execution is offset by   :
**(60 - actualSecond)**

For that we use this line :

```
int second = Calendar.getInstance (). get (Calendar.SECOND);
```

And here we have the second of the current time, we just have to know how much of the seconds (in **milliseconds**) remaining to arrive at the next **00s**

```
int delay = (60 - second) * 1000;
```

Now we all have to start our task for that we will use this method:

```
public void scheduleAtFixedRate (java.util.TimerTask task,
                                 long delay,
                                 long period)
```

**Params**:

> task – task to be scheduled.
>
> delay – delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
>
> period – time in milliseconds between successive task executions.

and this is the compelet Code :

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

int second = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND); // get the actual second 

System.out.println(second); // check the current second on this time 

int delay = (60 - second) * 1000; // this is the first delay to start the task

int period = 60000; // the period on millisSecond 

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //  start you task here
        // you can check the time by your self with the line below 
        Log.e(TAG, "run: " + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND));
    }
}, delay, period);
```

***Note*** : you can use  `timer.schedule()` method check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22487142/7085389) for more information